# How to construct a MySQL while loop PHP multidimensional array for datagrid framework

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, datagrid, multidimensional-array

I am not clear how to construct a multidimensional array to create a simple datagrid framework.  I have a number of class methods with crud select statements from MySQL tables in the format:

```
<?php

  function table1()
  {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table1`";
    $result = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);
    $html = "<table>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ))
    {
      $html .= "<tr><td>".$row['field_a']."</td><td>".$row['field_b']."</td></tr>";
    }
    $html .= "</table>";
    return $html;
  }

  function table2()
  {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table2`";
    $result_properties = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);
    $html = "<table>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ))
    {
      $html .= "<tr><td>".$row['field_x']."</td><td>".$row['field_y']."</td></tr>";
    }
    $html .= "</table>";
    return $html;
  }

?>
```

where the MySQL tables look like:

table1

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | bigint(12)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| field_a | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| field_b | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

table 2

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | bigint(12)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| field_x | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| field_y | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am trying to replace all these methods with a single datagrid method, selecting information about each individual table from two summary grid tables - one with properties of each table (table name and the select sql statement for that table) and the other with field names and headings for each individual table:

grid_properties

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(12)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| table      | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| select_sql | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

grid_fields

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | bigint(12)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| grid_properties_id | bigint(12)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| heading            | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| field              | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Data in the `grid_fields`.`field` column is intended to just be the field name of the table referenced in `grid_properties`.`table`, related through `grid_properties`.`id`::`grid_fields`.`grid_properties_id`.

The method I am using to construct the datagrid has a multidimensional array in the last while loop that has something wrong with it.  What is the correct way to construct this?

```
<?php

  function grid_schema($table)
  {
    // Get information about $table from the grid_properties table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `grid_properties` WHERE `table` LIKE '".$table."'";
    $result_properties = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);
    $properties = mysqli_fetch_array ($result1);
    $properties_sql = $properties['select_sql'];
    $id = $properties['id'];

    // Get information about the grid field names
    $fields_sql = "SELECT * FROM `grid_fields` WHERE `grid_properties_id` ='".$id."'";
    $fields_result = mysqli_query ($link, $fields_sql);

    // Display the Table Headings
    $html = "<table><tr>";
    while ($fields_row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $fields_result ))
    { $html .= "<th>".$fields_row['heading']."</th>"; }
    $html .= "</tr>";

    // Perform the SQL query from the grid_properties table
    $properties_result = mysqli_query ($link, $properties_sql);
    while ($properties_row = mysqli_fetch_array ($properties_result))
    {
      // Print out the contents of each row
      $html .= "<tr>";
      while ($fields_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $fields_result ))
      {
        // This is where I am having problems
        $html .= "<td>".$properties_row[$fields_row]['field']."</td>";
      }
    }
    $html .= "</table>";
    return $html;
  }
?>
```

Comment: It's hard to say as I'm not sure what your `grid_fields.field` column contains, but perhaps that should be `$properties_row[$fields_row['field']]`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @eggyal.  I tried moving the [ ], without success.  Data in the `grid_fields`.`field` column is intended to just be the field name of the table named referenced in `grid_properties`.`table`, related through `grid_properties`.`id`::`grid_fields`.`grid_properties_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    function grid_schema($table)
{
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

// Get information about $table from the grid_properties table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `grid_properties` WHERE `table` LIKE '".$table."'";
$result_properties = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);
$properties = mysqli_fetch_array ($result_properties, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$properties_sql = $properties['select_sql'];
$id = $properties['id'];

// Get information about the grid field names
$fields_sql = "SELECT * FROM `grid_fields` WHERE `grid_properties_id` ='".$id."'";
$fields_result = mysqli_query ($link, $fields_sql);

// Display the Table Headings
$html = "<table><tr>";
    $rows = array();
while ($fields_row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $fields_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
{
        $rows[] = $fields_row['field'];
        $html .= "<th>".$fields_row['heading']."</th>";
    }
$html .= "</tr>";

// Perform the SQL query from the grid_properties table
$properties_result = mysqli_query ($link, $properties_sql);
while ($properties_row = mysqli_fetch_array ($properties_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
// Print out the contents of each row
$html .= "<tr>";
foreach($rows as $row)
{
// This is where I am having problems
$html .= "<td>".$properties_row[$row]."</td>";
}
}
$html .= "</table>";
return $html;
}

echo grid_schema('table1');
```